# Finding the fundamental period by using four elementary operations (+,-,x,/)

Tags: periodic

The idea is to find the fundamental period of any periodic and bounded signal. This is all that we know about the signal. Nothing else. Only allowed operations are: $+,-,\times , \div$. We can also access any value of the signal that we desire.

How can a method be developed which finds or estimates the fundamental period of the given signal?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have posted a couple detailed answers to pitch detection using something like autocorrelation on this forum.  I'm on a phone and it's too difficult to find them and point to them.

Answer (score 1):

Well eventually operations such as the Fourier Transform and autocorrelation are defined with those four operations.

Are comparisons and conditional decision-making allowed?  Are you allowed to pick a pair of numbers from an array based on one of those numbers being a maximum?

[My other answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29962/how-to-deal-with-low-fundamental-when-using-amdf-for-pitch-extraction/29968#29968) is a place to begin.

Comment: About the pair of numbers, yes. Also about the comparison, but not quite sure about the conditional decision-making. But let's say yes for that too. How can it be solved?

Comment: In a computer, we call that a conditional *"branch"* or *"jump"* instruction.  In C or C++, it's the`if () {}` statement.

Comment: Look for my other posted answers.  One is about a low fundamental in it.

Comment: Okay now i get your point. Sure yes conditional can be used.

Comment: This is hard to do on a phone but [here is one answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29962/how-to-deal-with-low-fundamental-when-using-amdf-for-pitch-extraction/29968#29968).