# Calculate a signal of brightness

Tags: signal-analysis, python, frequency

I am new to signal processing. Currently, I am reading a paper regarding musical expression. The paper calculates brightness, and I want to reproduce their way of computing it. I was wondering if there's any way to calculate harmonic series from audio data, because I want to calculate the **Brightness**.

This is from a paper talking about a model called [MIDI-DDSP][2].
Here is the section I can't understand very well.

> Brightness is defined as the spectral centroid (in bin numbers) of the harmonic distribution,
> where $h_k(i)$ represents the $k$-th bin of the harmonic distribution, $h(τ)$ in the $i$-th time-step, and we use $|h|$ to refer to the number of bins in the harmonic distribution used by the DDSP module (we use $|h| = 60$, see Appendix B.2).

I am thinking of two ways. The first way is to use [spectral_centroid](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.feature.spectral_centroid.html) from Librosa.

The second way is to compute the frequency, and harmonic distribution. For example, the frequency of A4 note is 440, and I want the sum of `(440*1 + 880*2 + ..)` in A4 note.

However, I'm uncertain about the first way. And for the second way, is it correct or not? Any recommendation as to what tools I can use to calculate it?

Comment: It looks like you have intended to include an image, but there is not link included.

Comment: Oh, that can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The paper in question (which you forgot to link to, by the way), has an associated [Github](https://github.com/magenta/midi-ddsp). I suggest you start [there](https://github.com/magenta/midi-ddsp/blob/60ddf5bef43aebf67f4d5819ee8fb081a9631ec1/midi_ddsp/modules/interpretable_conditioning.py#L58).

Comment: Yeah, I've already read it. But the codes are so hard to understand. It's unclear

Comment: @Megan then you'll need to try and ask precise questions. If you know something is big, "can you explain this big thing to me, I don't tell you where I'm stuck at understanding it" is not a strategy that leads to answers.

Answer (score 0):

This definition of **brightness** of timbre in a musical note, and the use of the term **spectral centroid** was first suggested by the late James Beauchamp, in my recollection.  If your musical tone (think of the *"tone"* as being a slice of the musical note at approximately some time $t_0\ge0$ after the note onset) is:

$$\begin{align}
 x(t) &= x(t + \tfrac{1}{f_0}) \qquad \qquad & \forall t \approx t_0 \\
\\
  &= \sum\limits_{k=-K}^{K} c_k \, e^{j 2 \pi k f_0 t} \qquad \qquad &(c_{-k} = c_k^* \quad c_0 = 0) \\
\\
  &= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{K} 2|c_k| \, \cos(2 \pi k f_0 t + \phi_k)   \\
\end{align}$$

where

$$ c_k = f_0 \int\limits_{t_0}^{t_0+1/f_0} x(t) e^{-j 2 \pi k f_0 t} \ \mathrm{d}t $$

$$c_k \triangleq |c_k|\, e^{j \phi_k} \quad \text{and} \quad \phi_k \triangleq \arg\{c_k\}$$

Then the power of the tone is

$$ \overline{x^2(t)} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{K} 2|c_k|^2 $$

and the brightness of the tone is

$$  \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K} k |c_k|^2}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K} |c_k|^2} $$

Some other folks have defined the brightness to be:

$$  \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K} k^2 |c_k|^2}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K} |c_k|^2} $$

Still other used this definition for brightness:

$$  \frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{K} k |c_k|}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} |c_k|} $$

It turns out that the definition in the middle is the easiest to implement.  But, given these definitions, none of these definitions are functions of the fundamental frequency $f_0$.  So, either to extract the $c_k$ coefficients or, if you're using the simplest definition (with $k^2$) and a simple high-pass filter for a differentiator, you need to [compute the fundamental frequency](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29962/how-to-deal-with-low-fundamental-when-using-amdf-for-pitch-extraction/29968#29968) and use that in the calculation.

The first and second definition will be easiest to do.  We can talk about it, but first I want to get a feel for which way the OP wants to take it.